# After Patching Select Value From Dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have this list of ingredients that has their specific Unit of Measurements. However, each ingredient has two unit of measurement. The first_unit and the second_unit. How can i transfer it after patching value OR after selecting the ingredient? How can i filter out the unit of measurement dropdown according to its ingredient? Here;'s my stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-mtiiee?file=app/app.component.ts

```
patchValues(id,i) {
    let x = (<FormArray>this.addForm.controls['rows']).at(i);
    console.log(x);

    x.patchValue({
      unit_price: this.ingredients[id - 1].price,
      uom: this.ingredients[id - 1].first_unit.name,
      // uom: this.ingredients[id - 1].second_unit.name
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a form that some fields depending the value of an object, it's usefully that the value of a control was the own object, not only the "id" of the object
So, You can have a fbgroup with ingredientData, not with "id". Well, when you send the data to a service, not send the ingredientData, only the "id"

```
initGroup() {
    let rows = this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      ingredientData: ['', Validators.required], //<--see that not is ingredient_id
      unit_price: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      uom: ['', Validators.required],
    }))
}
```

Then your form will be like

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="ingredientData">
   <option value="null" hidden>-- Select Ingredient --</option>
   <option *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients" [ngValue]="ingredient">{{ingredient.name}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" formControlName="uom">
   <option value="null" hidden>-- Select Unit of Measure --</option>
   <option *ngIf="row.value.ingredientData" [value]="row.value.ingredientData.first_unit.id">
       {{row.value.ingredientData.first_unit.name}}
   </option>
   <option *ngIf="row.value.ingredientData" [value]="row.value.ingredientData.second_unit.id">
       {{row.value.ingredientData.second_unit.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

in un submit, we must "mappear" the response like

```
onSubmit(){
    const data = {
      ingredient: this.addForm.get('rows').value.map((x)=>{
        //from each row, we create a new object
        return {
           id:x.ingredientData.id,
           unit_price:x.ingredientData.price,
           uom:x.uom
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: Can you check this updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-mtiiee?file=app/app.component.ts. Why does UOM doesn't change when i change ingredients?

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo. So how can i get the ingredient_id so that unit_price could be patch? Here's the updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-mtiiee?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I supouse that you can write < input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit Price" [value]="row.value.ingredientData.price"  >, but look that it's not belong to the FormGroup and that, the Unit Price is the same in differents unit of Measue. That's have no sense. The Price must be a propertie of the unit's of measure

Comment: Ok. I just need help on how can i get the ingredient_id since you use [ngValue]="ingredient". How can i extract it?

Comment: The result in the console.log is ingredient_id
:
"2: Object". How would i extract just it's id?

Comment: And one thing. When i submit it, the UOM should only contain the one value and that is it's id. How come i have several data of it? Here's the update link https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-mtiiee?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I update the anwser add "submit" function. ¡Be Carefully! In the options, must be [value]="...", (see is between []) not only value=